# How do i find out which script is inserting into mysql db without viewing a million files?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do i find out which script is inserting into mysql db without viewing a million files?

Comment: Search the source for files containing "INSERT".  It would help to know if this was for windows or *nix, but this is easily a www.superuser.com issue

Comment: If you're on Windows, I find a very useful app for searching sourcecode is dngrep.  Check out http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very general approach, if you're on Unix or Mac, is to type:

```
find . -name "[script pattern]" -exec grep -Hn "[search pattern]" {} \;
```

where `script pattern` is something like `*.sh` that matches your script and `search pattern` is something that will match the insertion command you're looking for.

`find` is a *nix program that finds all files in a directory and its subdirectories, the `.` is where to search from (replace it with `/` if you want to search your entire machine, but be prepared to wait awhile, and you might want to redirect error output to `/dev/null`). `-exec` is an option in `find` that runs a program on the files it finds, `grep` is a search engine, `-Hn` tells it to report the file name and line number where it finds the pattern requested, and `{} \;` is just syntactic sugar required by the `-exec` option.